# Symfony 5.1 - Cannot autowire service

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, autowired

I want to refactoring my code, but now i have error and don't understand what.
Objectif : Don't need to pass parameters when call TokenService, and use autowiring to autowiring EntityManager & Request, and don't set it when controller call service.

> Cannot resolve argument $tokenService of  App\Controller\TokenController::showTokens()
> Cannot autowire service  App\Service\TokenService
> argument  $request  of method  __construct()  references class  Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request  but no such service exists.

**Before :**

/src/Controller/TokenController.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Service\TokenService;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * @Route("/v1")
 */
class TokenController
{
   /** @var EntityManagerInterface $em */
    private $em;
    /** @var Request $request */
    private $request;

    /**
     * TokenService constructor.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
     */
    public function __construct(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function showTokens(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em): JsonResponse
    {
        $tokenService = new TokenService($request, $em);

        return $tokenService->getTokens();
    }
}
```

/src/Service/TokenService.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

/**
 * Class TokenService
 * @package App\Service
 */
class TokenService
{
    /** @var EntityManagerInterface $em */
    private $em;
    /** @var Request $request */
    private $request;

    /**
     * TokenService constructor.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
     */
    public function __construct(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function getTokens()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**After :**

/config/services.yaml

```yaml
parameters:

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true

    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'
            - '../src/Tests/'

    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller/'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    App\Service\TokenService: ~
```

/src/Controller/TokenController.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Service\TokenService;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * @Route("/v1")
 */
class TokenController
{
    public function showTokens(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em, TokenService $tokenService): JsonResponse
    {
        return $tokenService->getTokens();
    }
```

/src/Service/TokenService.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
/**
 * Class TokenService
 * @package App\Service
 */
class TokenService
{
    /** @var EntityManagerInterface $em */
    private $em;
    /** @var Request $request */
    private $request;

    /**
     * TokenService constructor.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
     */
    public function __construct(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function getTokens()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/request.html Be sure to understand why you inject a request stack instead of a request.

Comment: It's for exemple ! Request is use after by Service, i have post easy code to don't complicated situation.
I have write objectif and error

Comment: I confess that I have no idea what your comment is saying.  The error message tells you exactly where the problem is.  The link I posted tells you how to fix it.

Comment: I think we don't understand each other. I can retrieve the request in the service very well, since it is passed as an argument via instantiation in the controller. Except that I find it useless in the controller, for all the calls made to this service, to systematically have to provide Request/EntityManager, so I want to pass through the injection of dependencies so that both can be used from the service, without having to provide them during instantiation.

Comment: You are correct in that we clearly do not understand each other.  Which is fine.  Maybe someone else will come along.  But I am very curious as to how you think that the error message: "Cannot autowire service App\Service\TokenService argument $request of method __construct()" means that you have successfully injected the request service?  Especially since there is no request service. Your controller should of course be doing return $tokenService->getTokens($request); but that is almost irrelevant.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack

Comment: Nice, i have understand my mistake ! I have use your answer and it's work fine. Use RequestStack, and remove all "request args" in controller, and service work fine with autowire !
You can use it (and docs) on anwser, and i upvote you to resolve it ! Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess it's been awhile since we had a good request stack question.  I did a bit of a search and did not find any answer that was directly applicable and provided a decent explanation.

The basic issue is that the Symfony framework supports nested requests.  You get these, for example, when using embedded controllers.  So there is no actual request service.  There actually used to be when Symfony 2.0 was first released but it was a real mess.  Supporting nested request services was done at the container level and it was not fun.

So a big hammer known as the [request stack](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack) was introduced to solve the problem once and for all.  You [inject the request stack](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/request.html) instead of the request and then access the request when you actually need it.

```
class TokenService
{
    private $em;
    private $requestStack;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function getTokens()
    {
        $request = $this->requestStack->getMainRequest(); // or possibly getCurrentRequest depending on where the tokens are
        return true;
    }
```

Having said that, I would personally just pass the request from the controller.  Doing so gets rid of that 'it depends' comment of mine.  I also thinks it reduces the 'magic' involved just a bit.  Both approaches will work.

```
class TokenService
{
    public function getTokens(Request $request)
    {
        return true;
    }
...
class TokenController
{
    public function showTokens(Request $request, TokenService $tokenService): JsonResponse
    {
        return $tokenService->getTokens($request);
    }
```